# Is canvas.save/restore or canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap,Matrix,Paint) better?

Tags: android, performance, graphics, matrix

Which is the difference between these two code snippets?

```java
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image)
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.postRotate(angle, bmp.getWidth()/2, bmp.getHeight()/2);
m.postTranslate(x,y);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp,m,null);
```

Or:

```java
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image)
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(angle, bmp.getWidth()/2, bmp.getHeight()/2);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x, y, null);
canvas.restore();
```

Is there a performance difference? Is it worth caching the Matrix in option 1 if I am trying to achieve a high framerate?

Comment: For performance questions, the right answer is often "measure it". If the difference is small enough that you're not sure which is betterm, then just go with the version that's clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are calling `canvas.save()` and `canvas.restore()` in only one of the examples, but I have done performance tests and show:

- Using `Matrix` seems consistently faster (usually by 30-50%), for loading the same image.
- However, some tests shows `Canvas` eventually was faster: after 300,000
  tests - by 4-15%.

So if you need to load it a few times, use `Matrix`.
If you need to load it hundreds of thousands of times - you may be better off using only `Canvas` (or at least reusing the same `Matrix` instance).

Comment: My results don't differ quite so much but I get the same trend in that the Canvas method seems faster with loads of renders. I guess there probably isn't enough in it to worry about.

Comment: glad it helped, if not only to confirm what you were seeing.